# How to submit data into 2 table in database at same time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I already successfully insert data to [Survey] table.

But I also want to append data(amount) into [Vote] table at the same time which will increase the data(amount) +1 to the selected Pizza the user select when they click submit.

Last if can complete this step, I will need to build a pie chart with Chart.js  retrieve from database which i already created but it is set manually in the script by me. Scroll to the end, to check chart.js pie chart.

Currently Vote = 0.

[[Vote] table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiose.png)

Here is my SQL query (I create a dbml item called "myconnection")

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Survey] 
(
    [SurveyId]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberName] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [PizzaVote]  VARCHAR(100) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SurveyId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vote] 
(
    [VoteId]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PizzaName] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [amount]    INT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([VoteId] ASC)
);
```

Here is my `Survey.aspx` markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Survey.aspx.cs" Inherits="MYDemo.Survey" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1" colspan="2">
                <h1>Survey</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Name</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSurName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Preferred Pizza?</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrePizza" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Island Supreme</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Hawaiian Supreme</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Blazing Seafood</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Chicken Pepperoni</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Deluxe Cheese</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Island Tuna</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Haiwaiian Chicken</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlPrePizza" ErrorMessage="Please select one pizza!" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code behind.(survey.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MYDemo
{
    public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Survey (MemberName,PizzaVote) values(@MemberName, @PizzaVote)", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberName", txtSurName.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PizzaVote", ddlPrePizza.SelectedItem.Text);

                con.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                txtSurName.Text = string.Empty;
                ddlPrePizza.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Pie Chart that I created with Chart.js.

```
<%--<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChartJS.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoginAndRegister.ChartJS" %>--%>
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChartJS.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoginAndRegister.ChartJS" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" runat="server">

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <%--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>--%>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <%--<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Online Survey on <span class="auto-style1"><strong>10000</strong></span> customer on their Prefer Pizza in Best Pizza</h1>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <%--<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>--%>


        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: ["ISLAND SUPREME", "HAWAIIAN SUPREME", "BLAZING SEAFOOD", "CHICKEN PEPPERONI", "DELUXE CHEESE", "ISLAND TUNA", "HAWAIIAN CHICKEN"],
                    datasets: [{
                        backgroundColor: [
                          "#2ecc71",
                          "#3498db",
                          "#95a5a6",
                          "#9b59b6",
                          "#f1c40f",
                          "#e74c3c",
                          "#34495e"
                        ],
                        data: [1000, 1309, 2003, 1117, 1028, 1024, 2007]
                    }]
                }
            });
        </script>
            </div>
    <%--</form>--%>

</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode . Pictures are no use. Not searchable, not copyable, not easily viewable even. Images are good if they add context to the question, but are not the whole story. Please edit your question to be usable. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have updated my post now.

Comment: PizzaVote should be a foreign key ID to the vote table. then it uniquely identifies the pizza, not relying on descriptions which could change etc. Anyway to meet your requirement just write an UPDATE statement to the Vote table to modify the row of the selected ID (from your dropdown) increment the existing value of `amount` by 1

Comment: Ok, I will change it to binding method which dropdownlist(PizzaVote) can get data direct from [Vote] (PizzaName) table and then change to foreign key.

Comment: One other small thing - spelling correction: "Preffered" should be "Preferred" :-)

Comment: But i still no idea how to update the amount of vote +1 in [Vote] table when user click submit Button.

Comment: Simple update statement: `UPDATE Vote SET amount = amount + 1 WHERE VoteId = @Id`

Comment: Side note: Technically you don't actually need to store the amount in a separate field. Whenever you need to know the current amount of votes for a Pizza, you could simply write a SELECT statement to count the number of rows in Survey where the value of PizzaVote equals the ID of the pizza. A GROUP BY query would let you return the results for all the pizzas at once.

Comment: Thank you Adyson, I have solve my problem with your help. I found I learn a lot from you. Do you have any ideas how to retrieve data and display on pie chart with Chart.js?

Comment: No, sorry I don't know that product. Don't they have a tutorial which includes binding to a data source, or fetching data from the server in some way?

Comment: I found it very hard with those uploaded video, and mostly is mysql or php database. By the way thank you again for your help. I will ask other for the chart.js.